# Visual Basic edit Word documents in bulk

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have hundreds of docx-documents which I would like to edit in bulk with a visual basic macro. They all share an id on the first line which looks like this:

```
9-ZKB-S
```

Or

```
12-JK-17
```

I would like to remove the '-' from the id so it will become like this:

```
9ZKBS
```

Or

```
12JK17
```

Then somewhere in the document I have a word followed by a number like this:

```
Productionnumber. 42-563-12
```

And I also would like to remove the minus character:

```
Productionnumber. 4256312
```

I've found a visual basic script which enables me to select a folder containing word-documents and to perform a search and replace. But I don't know how to do the specific things I've mentioned such as:

- In each document, remove the - and the space between characters on the first line
- In each document, remove the - and the space between characters after *Productionnumber.*

  ```
  Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim MyDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 500) As String '100 files is the    maximum applying this code
  On Error Resume Next
  Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  With MyDialog
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.docx", 1
  .AllowMultiSelect = True
  i = 1
  If .Show = -1 Then
  For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
  GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
  i = i + 1
  Next
  i = i - 1
  End If
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For j = 1 To i Step 1
  Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
  Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
  With Selection.Find
  .Text = "search" 'Find What
  .Replacement.Text = "find" 'Replace With
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindAsk
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchByte = True
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Application.Run macroname:="NEWMACROS"
  ActiveDocument.Save
  ActiveWindow.Close
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End With
  MsgBox "operation end, please view", vbInformation
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Using wildcards](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/using_wildcards.html) and test the pattern in word first. For example (not tested):

```
With Doc.Range.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "<(?*)>\-<(?*)>\-<(?*)>"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1\2\3" 'Replace With
    ' ... the rest of the options
End With
```